# prototype and constructor property in JS

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

Code snippet is following, Can anyone explain why `a.hasOwnProperty("prototype")` is true, the others are false? Does it mean function has its own prototype, the others are inherited from Object?If so, why `c.hasOwnProperty("prototype")` is false? Besides, where does property of their `constructor` property come from? Thanks

```
    var a = function () {
    };
    var b = new String("test");
    var c = {};

    console.log(a.hasOwnProperty("prototype"));//true
    console.log(b.hasOwnProperty("prototype"));//false
    console.log(c.hasOwnProperty("prototype"));//false
    console.log(a.hasOwnProperty("constructor"));//false
    console.log(b.hasOwnProperty("constructor"));//false
    console.log(c.hasOwnProperty("constructor"));//false
    console.log(a.constructor);//Function()
    console.log(b.constructor);//String()
    console.log(c.constructor);//Object()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype property is only available on a constructor function. 'a' is a function and thus has a prototype. 'b' and 'c' are instances. They do not have prototypes, their constructors have prototypes:

```
console.log(a.constructor.hasOwnProperty("prototype")) // true
console.log(b.constructor.hasOwnProperty("prototype")) // true
console.log(c.constructor.hasOwnProperty("prototype")) // true
```

Comment: thanks. btw, a.hasOwnProperty("constructor") return false, does it mean the constructor property is inherited from Object?

Comment: Yes, check: Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("constructor")